# BI Publisher - Customize Data Source over RTF-Template

Tags: templates, xslt, bi-publisher

I use a SQL query to select my required data, but there are not all required data in the database that I need.

I customized the data source with an XSL script to use them in my template.

The XSL-Script get the Datasource and Tranform it to a new XML-Structure.

How can I reach the customized data source into my template?

Everytime the data source must be customized before the reports are created.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to create a `Data model` with Data source as `File` (`Data Set` screen > `General Settings` > `Type`). In the `Details` section of the screen select the path name (you can define a path name by navigating to `Admin > Data Sources > File`, the path should be on your OBI Application server). Next enter the `xml` file name in the `File Name` field (on the `Data Set` screen `Details` section). This `XML` file should be the source of your `rtf` or `xls` template and should be placed under the directory you defined in `Admin` options.

The XSL script should update (overwrite) `XML` file periodically.